# Aggregation with repeating events in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal-views, repeating-events

I am trying to create a View counting contacts who attended various repeating events. Each contact needs to be counted once for each repeating event, so I want to group by the event name, not its ID.
I base my View on Participants. My View shows two fields; Event Title and Contact ID. I Group By on Event Title and Count Distinct on the Contact ID.
[image]
However, the resulting query includes the Event ID in the select list, so I end up grouping on Event ID instead of Event Title.
[image]
Is there a way to stop views including the Event ID in the Select Statement?

Would be most grateful for any solution or workarounds.

Comment: I have a similar problem here : https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/views-how-to-sort-by-membership-type